# How to set nested objects?

Tags: react-redux, immutable.js

i am trying to set the redux state but not the whole object tree but just a sub-tree.

Object graph -

```
Parent
 |----Header
 |----Summary
         |-----List of objects
```

I am using following code -

```
return state.setIn([Parent, 'Summary'], summary)
```

It sets the summary object but the list of objects is null. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try it in this way:

```
let newSummary = Object.assign(Parent.summary, {...yourchange});
this.setState(Object.assign(Parent.summary, {
    summary: newSummary
})})
```